# How do I write a query to determine if I'm running out of ID space across all tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that I can use in a monitor to warn me if I'm close to exceeding the 32bit integer space for a sequence of IDs.

I know I can get a list of all tables like so:

```
SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public'
```

And then loop over each one, querying (e.g.):

```
SELECT last_value FROM users_id_seq
```

1. Is there a way to combine those into a single query?
2. Is there a way to exclude tables that are already using bigint for their ID?

Comment: You will need several queries to do that; perhaps you can create a PL/pgSQL function for convenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the table a sequence is "related" to, you can use something like this:

```sql
SELECT seq_ns.nspname as sequence_schema,
       seq.relname    as sequence_name,
       tab_ns.nspname as table_schema,
       tab.relname    as related_table,
       s.last_value,
       s.max_value
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class seq
         INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace seq_ns ON seq.relnamespace = seq_ns.oid
         INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_depend d ON d.objid = seq.oid AND d.deptype = 'a'
         INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class tab ON d.objid = seq.oid AND d.refobjid = tab.oid
         INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace tab_ns ON tab.relnamespace = tab_ns.oid
         INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_sequences s ON s.schemaname = seq_ns.nspname AND s.sequencename = seq.relname
WHERE seq.relkind = 'S'
  AND seq_ns.nspname = '<your-schema-name>';
```